# Chaging LSI projection Type at runtime

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am doing query Expression on dynamo DB based on LSI and the projection type for the LSI is set as INCLUDE. How can I change LSI projection to INCLUDE ALL at runtime?.I see that projectionExpression can be changed  but is it feasible .if yes please let me know

```
Projection projection = new Projection().withProjectionType(ProjectionType.ALL);

queryExpression.setProjectionExpression()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this. Your projected attributes are copied into your LSI on write, so trying to read additional projected values at runtime is asking for data that is not there.

Indexes in dynamo are just copies of your data inserted against another key. Dynamo manages this duplication behind the scenes and keeps your indexes and main table in sync.

**You'll need to re-create your table with an LSI that projects ALL**. I believe the projection API you're using is for when you project ALL but may want a subset of ALL to be returned.

> A projection is the set of attributes that is copied from a table into a secondary index. The partition key and sort key of the table are always projected into the index; you can project other attributes to support your application's query requirements. When you query an index, Amazon DynamoDB can access any attribute in the projection as if those attributes were in a table of their own.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LSI.html